# Subtracting a varibale obtained as output of commands and an integer in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am finding out the total ideal CPU by using the command

> top -bn1 | grep Cpu | awk -F"," '{print $4}' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g' | sed 's/%id//'

Now I want to find out the CPU which is being used so I am trying to subtract the output of the command from 100

So the script looks like :

```
i=`top -bn1 | grep Cpu | awk -F"," '{print $4}' | sed 's/[ \t]*//g' | sed 's/%id//'`
j=100
k=$(( ${j}-${i} ))
echo $k
```

When executing this script the output gives an error:

> 100-93.0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 ")

How should I proceed to subtract the derived decimal number from 100 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because BASH arithmetic cannot handle floating point numbers and you will get same error while running this command in `bash`:

```
((100-93.0))
```

But you can skip `grep`, `sed` and all `bash` directives. Just a single `awk` can handle this computation like this:

```
top -bn1 | awk -F, '/Cpu/ {print 100-$4}'
```

Comment: the given solution worked like a charm but, this is still situation specific as there was a work around this problem by avoiding grep, sed, etc. How would I subtract when faced with a situation where I have to subtract a floating point number from an integer ?

Comment: As I wrote, you cannot do floating point math in BASH. Use `bc -l` OR `awk` for that.